# Merge two rows with different date but with the same attributes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have this query

```
SELECT te.user_name, LEFT(te.entry_datetime, 10) AS entry_date, cin.entry_datetime AS timein, cout.entry_datetime AS timeout
FROM time_entries te
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_name, LEFT(entry_datetime, 10) AS entry_date, MIN(entry_datetime) AS entry_datetime
    FROM time_entries
    WHERE entry_type = 'Time In'
    GROUP BY user_name, entry_date
) cin ON cin.user_name = te.user_name AND cin.entry_date = LEFT(te.entry_datetime, 10)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_name, LEFT(entry_datetime, 10) AS entry_date, MAX(entry_datetime) AS entry_datetime
    FROM time_entries
    WHERE entry_type = 'Time Out'
    GROUP BY user_name, entry_date
) cout ON cout.user_name = te.user_name AND cout.entry_date = LEFT(te.entry_datetime, 10)
GROUP BY te.user_name, entry_date;
```

This is the output [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98d5a/1)

```
USER_NAME|  ENTRY_DATE   | TIMEIN    | TIMEOUT
User1    | 28-JUL-13     | 16:40:40  | 16:42:30
User2    | 28-JUL-13     | 16:41:13  | 16:41:15
```

But I found a loop hole in the solution, their are some employees that works overnight and time-out the following day. So when the user let say time-in on July, 28 2013 and time-out on July, 29 2013 this will going to be the output. [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e10e/1)

```
USER_NAME|  ENTRY_DATE   | TIMEIN   | TIMEOUT
User1    | 28-JUL-13     | 16:40:40 | null
User1    | 29-JUL-13     | null     | 16:42:30
User2    | 28-JUL-13     | 16:41:13 | 16:41:15
```

The logic is right but seems not appriate in my case. I'm thinking just to make the job easier just remove ENTRY_DATE and only have 3 columns USER_NAME, TIMEIN and TIMEOUT. Something like this.

```
USER_NAME   | TIMEIN              | TIMEOUT
User1       | 28-JUL-13 16:40:40  | 29-JUL-13 16:42:30
User2       | 28-JUL-13 16:41:13  | 28-JUL-13 16:41:15
```

Could anyone help me to figure out what am I going to change or suggest a new solution? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I was able to solved my own problem. Here is the solution I found as a **NEWBIE** [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2eaa2/1)

```
SELECT te.user_name, date(te.entry_datetime) as date, te3.entry_datetime as Timein, te2.entry_datetime as Timeout
FROM time_entries te

JOIN time_entries te3 ON te.user_name = te3.user_name
AND te3.entry_type='Time In' AND te3.entry_datetime =
    (SELECT entry_datetime
     FROM time_entries
     WHERE entry_type='Time In' AND user_name=te.user_name AND entry_datetime = te.entry_datetime
     GROUP By entry_datetime)

LEFT JOIN time_entries te2 ON te.user_name = te2.user_name
AND te2.entry_type='Time Out' AND te2.entry_datetime =
    (SELECT entry_datetime
    FROM time_entries
    WHERE entry_type='Time Out' AND user_name=te.user_name AND entry_datetime > te.entry_datetime
    ORDER BY
    ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, te.entry_datetime, 'entry_datetime'))
    LIMIT 1)
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
USER_NAME|    DATE     | TIMEIN              | TIMEOUT
User1    |  28-JUL-13  | 28-JUL-13 16:40:40  | 29-JUL-13 16:42:30
User2    |  29-JUL-13  | 29-JUL-13 16:43:16  | null
User1    |  30-JUL-13  | 30-JUL-13 16:47:16  | 31-JUL-13 16:50:32
```

btw I decided not to remove the date anymore because I also found it useful.

**NOTE: THIS MAY NOT BE THE BEST ANSWER NOR BEST DESIGN OR ARCHITECTURE BUT THIS IS THE BEST THAT CAN I DO AS A NEWBIE IN SQL. IF YOU HAVE BETTER SOLUTION THAN THIS PLEASE SHARE IT AND NOT JUST BARK AROUND THANKS. :)**

Comment: This may work, but I'm afraid it does so by luck rather than design, and should not be relied upon as a solution.

Comment: Well yes I understand that because I'm just a newbie on sql. I'm just starting to learn and not yet good at design. But its the fact that I tried and did my best to do it and didn't just depend on the answers of others. I know this may not be the best solution but it's ok because it satisfies my needs. Rather than to wait for years to have an answer with good at design.